# Boolean variable in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, boolean

I have definition of `Boolean` variable in Webdriver backed as:

```
boolean r1 = selenium.isTextPresent("something");
```

I used this in `while` loop. I want convert my code to Webdriver code and I tried:

```
boolean jr1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("something")) != null;
```

But it works only when text is present and value is `true`. When value should be returned as `false` to my variable i receive in console error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"something"}
```

Can you give me any suggestions how i can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got around this by writing an isElementPresent method that returns true or false.
Edit - Having just seen this exact method in another answer, I no longer believe I wrote it. Apparently I found it ages ago and have been using it for so long that it feels like mine! All credit to original author

```
private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
  try {
    driver.findElement(by);
    return true;
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can then use:

```
boolean jr1 = isElementPresent(By.linkText("Something"));
```

Add this method to a base class and extend your test class from it, Or add it to each of your test classes.

Answer (score 1):

For me the most straightforward implementation of isTextPresent as webdriver code is the following:

```
public boolean isTextPresent(String text) {
   String allText = webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
   boolean isTextPresent = allText.contains(text);
   return isTextPresent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element does not have the linktext 'something' Webdriver will always return the exception I'm afraid.

Have you tried the Expected Conditions?

```
try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("something")
        Boolean jr1 = True
    }
catch (Exception e) {
        Boolen jr1 = False
    }
```

It's a rather rough implementation but in this case I will try to find the element, if it finds it, True. If the request times out, False.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using following approach:

1. Initially I set the value of boolean msg not displayed to false
2. waited for 50 seconds until element is clickable
3. if the text in the table equals displayed text i.e. no records then return true
4. else return false

   public boolean isRecordDisplayed(String sDisplayText) {
               Boolean isNoRecordDisplayedMsg = false;
               WebElement search = (new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(table)));

   ```
           if (search.getText().equals(sDisplayText)) {
               isNoRecordDisplayedMsg = true;
           }
           return isRecordHostDisplayedMsg;
       }
   ```

   By table = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'record')]//th");